# List creation of double values with UserOption enum

Tags: c#

I have looked through the archives and didn't find anything that was able to specifically help me understand the problem I'm working through. It is most likely extremely easy but I am finding the structural components of building the program challenging to understand. I think it's the concept of using methods and then calling the results of those methods to Main.

I need to create a List of values, which a user can Add, Sum (+Print result) and Print(as value is entered) - they select this via an enum. The program runs while the user wishes to use any of the above options so there needs to be a loop.

Here is what I have produced so far - there are no errors but there is no 'connectivity' in the code either. My enum works and that's about it. I am unsure how to "call" the methods NewValue, Sum and Print. Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE - I've just looked back through some of the comments up on my updated code and I didn't realise what the correct protocol was when working through answers. I have now updated what I thought was the best response to my question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SplashKitSDK;

public class Program    
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        UserOption userSelection;

        do
        {
            userSelection = ReadUserOption();

            switch (userSelection)
            {
                case UserOption.NewValue:
                    //NewValue (_values);
                    break;
                case UserOption.Sum:
                    //Sum ();
                    break;
                case UserOption.Print:
                    //Print ();
                    break;
                case UserOption.Quit:
                    Console.WriteLine("Quit");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (userSelection != UserOption.Quit);
    }

    public static UserOption ReadUserOption()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 0 to add a value");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to add a sum all values");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 to print a sum all values");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 to quit");

        int option = 3;
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out option);

        return (UserOption) option;
    }

    public static int ReadInteger(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter a valid integer");
            }
        }
    }

    public static int ReadDouble(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter a valid double");
            }
        }
    }

    public enum UserOption
    {
        NewValue, Sum, Print, Quit
    }
}

public class List
{
    private static List<double> _values = new List<double>();

    public int Size
    {
        get
        {
            return _values.Count;
        }
    }

    public static void NewValue (double value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value");
        value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        _values.Add(value);
    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        foreach (double value in _values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    public static void Sum()
    {
        double sum = 0;

        foreach (double value in _values)
        {
            sum = sum + (value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Sum of all elements in the list is {sum}");
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the question isn't clear, can you be more specific ?

Comment: How do I 'call' NewValue, Sum and Print to Main - I am unsure of how to incorporate them into the Switch. How do I create a loop for the User to continue to use the programs function until they decide to exit (option 3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design-wise, I wouldn't create List class with static methods, so the methods NewValue, Print and Sum become instance-related methods. Also, the NewValue(double value) doesn't need the parameter, since it handles the reading part itself.

Code-wise, these are the changes needed in the main (looks like your'e on the right track), they won't compile without the previously described changes, but I'll leave the to you :)

```
    public static void Main()
{
    UserOption userSelection;
    List myList = new List();
    do
    {
        userSelection = ReadUserOption();

        switch (userSelection)
        {
            case UserOption.NewValue:
                myList.NewValue();
                break;
            case UserOption.Sum:
                myList.Sum();
                break;
            case UserOption.Print:
                myList.Print();
                break;
            case UserOption.Quit:
                Console.WriteLine("Quit");
                break;
        }
    }
    while (userSelection != UserOption.Quit);
}
```

Simply explained, you want to create an instance of List, and do all of your manipulations on the object in hand - myList. From there, everything is pretty much straight forward.

Edit:
A few word about the 'static' keyword - in this context, 'static' for methods means you can call them without any instance: List.NewValue(...).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear enough to me, but to just make it work as your code suggest you've intended, there's not too much to do.

**1** - I didn't see a need for the ReadInteger and ReadDouble methods.

**2** - I've removed the `value` parameter from `NewValue` method, once it's already making a read before to add.

```
public static void NewValue ()
{
    double val = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value");
    val = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    _values.Add(val);
}
```

**3** - Once the methods and the list itself on `List` class are static, you have no need to instantiate it. So you could call it just like this:

```
switch (userSelection)
{
    case UserOption.NewValue:
        List.NewValue();
        break;
    case UserOption.Sum:
        List.Sum();
        break;
    case UserOption.Print:
        List.Print();
        break;
    case UserOption.Quit:
        Console.WriteLine("Quit");
        break;
}
```

[This example is working on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7hlytk). If it's not what you need, please clarify your question.